# Rate of change in matlab

Tags: matlab

i have plotted a graph between time vs theta when time increases theta decreases up to some time ofter that it started increasing  now i want to find what rate it is decreasing.      equation theta=exp(-t/tau) i have to find tau ?  can any one help me please..

Comment: Looking for this http://nl.mathworks.com/help/econ/autocorr.html#btzjcln-4?

Comment: And http://nl.mathworks.com/help/econ/autocorrelation-and-partial-autocorrelation.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear from your question where you think that your problem is.  But, when I read your question, it sounds like you are trying to fit an equation to some real data.  Specifically, it sounds like: (1) you have some real data, (2) only part of the data is interesting to you, and (3) for that interesting data, you want to fit it to the equation `theta=exp(-t/tau)`.

If that is indeed what you want, then you first must find just those data points that you think should be fit with the equation.  I would plot your data points and then, by eye, decide which are the ones that are relevant to you.  Discard the rest.

Next, you need to fit them to your equation.  Since your equation is an exponential, the easiest way to find "tau" is to convert it to a linear equation.  When you do this, you get  'log(theta) = -t / tau'.  Or, said similarly, `log(theta) = -1/tau * t`.

If you take the log of all of your theta data points and plot them versus t, you should see a straight line.  If this is truly the equation that will match your data, your data points should go through `log(theta) = 0.0` at `t = 0.0`.  If so, you can find tau by evaluating the slope of the line:  `slope = mean(log(theta)./t)`. Then, `tau = -1/slope`.

If your data points did not go through zero, you will need to shift them by some time offset so that they do go through zero.  Then you can evaluate the slope and get your tau value.

This isn't really a Matlab question, by the way.  Computationally, this is a very simple problem, so if Matlab is new to you, you might be making this harder than it needs to be.  It could just as easily be done in Excel (or any spreadsheet) or whatever tool might be easier to use.